# Can ALL string be decoded as valid binary data?

Tags: string, base64

As known, Base-64 encodes binary data into transferable ASCII strings, and we decode these strings back to data.

Now my question is inverted: Can every random string be decoded as binary data, and correctly encoded back to the exact original string?

Comment: Decoded as _what_? And what does "valid" mean?  Are you asking for UTF8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon your coding method - some methods use only a limited range of characters so a string containing other characters would not be legal. In Base64 this is the case so the answer is no. With other methods I'm sure its possible but I cannot think of an example other than simply treating the string as binary bytes.

Comment: UTF-8 string. Seems I should keep some limit: The string contains UTF-8 characters except for: '\t', '\r', '\n. But white space (blank), '/', '-', '_' may be included.